# What is Ruby's analog to Python Metaclasses?

Tags: python, ruby, metaprogramming, metaclass

Python has the idea of metaclasses that, if I understand correctly, allow you to modify an object of a class at the moment of construction. You are not modifying the class, but instead the object that is to be created then initialized.

Python (at least as of 3.0 I believe) also has the idea of class decorators. Again if I understand correctly, class decorators allow the modifying of the class definition at the moment it is being declared.

Now I believe there is an equivalent feature or features to the class decorator in Ruby, but I'm currently unaware of something equivalent to metaclasses. I'm sure you can easily pump any Ruby object through some functions and do what you will to it, but is there a feature in the language that sets that up like metaclasses do?

So again, Does Ruby have something similar to Python's metaclasses?

**Edit** I was off on the metaclasses for Python. A metaclass and a class decorator do very similar things it appears. They both modify the class when it is defined but in different manners. Hopefully a Python guru will come in and explain better on these features in Python.

But a class or the parent of a class can implement a `__new__(cls[,..])` function that does customize the construction of the object before it is initialized with `__init__(self[,..])`.

**Edit** This question is mostly for discussion and learning about how the two languages compare in these features. I'm familiar with Python but not Ruby and was curious. Hopefully anyone else who has the same question about the two languages will find this post helpful and enlightening.

Comment: Hmm... I may be still missing something but after reading a couple of links it's starting to sound like Python's metaclass and Ruby's metaclass are different. I'll hopefully get a chance to do more research and post about what I have learned. That is of course unless someone knows.

Links:
[Katz on Metaclasses](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/),

[Metaclass and Ruby internals](http://www.klankboomklang.com/2007/10/05/the-metaclass/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have metaclasses. There are some constructs in Ruby which some people sometimes wrongly call metaclasses but they aren't (which is a source of *endless* confusion).

However, there's a lot of ways to achieve the same results in Ruby that you would do with metaclasses. But without telling us what exactly you want to do, there's no telling what those mechanisms might be.

In short:

- Ruby doesn't have metaclasses
- Ruby doesn't have any one construct that corresponds to Python's metaclasses
- Everything that Python can do with metaclasses can also be done in Ruby
- But there is no *single* construct, you will use different constructs depending on what exactly you want to do
- Any one of those constructs probably has other features as well that do not correspond to metaclasses (although they probably correspond to something *else* in Python)
- While you can do anything in Ruby that you can do with metaclasses in Python, it might not necessarily be straightforward
- Although often there will be a more Rubyish solution that *is* elegant
- Last but not least: while you can do anything in Ruby that you can do with metaclasses in Python, doing it might not necessarily be The Ruby Way

So, what *are* metaclasses exactly? Well, they are classes of classes. So, let's take a step back: what are *classes* exactly?

Classes …

- are factories for objects
- define the behavior of objects
- define on a metaphysical level what it means to be an instance of the class

For example, the `Array` class produces array objects, defines the behavior of arrays and defines what "array-ness" means.

Back to metaclasses.

Metaclasses …

- are factories for classes
- define the behavior of classes
- define on a metaphysical level what it means to be a class

In Ruby, those three responsibilities are split across three different places:

- the `Class` class creates classes and defines a little bit of the behavior
- the individual class's eigenclass defines a little bit of the behavior of the class
- the concept of "classness" is hardwired into the interpreter, which also implements the bulk of the behavior (for example, you cannot inherit from `Class` to create a new kind of class that looks up methods differently, or something like that – the method lookup algorithm is hardwired into the interpreter)

So, those three things together play the role of metaclasses, but neither one of those is a metaclass (each one only implements a small part of what a metaclass does), nor is the *sum* of those the metaclass (because they do much more than that).

Unfortunately, some people call eigenclasses of classes metaclasses. (Until recently, I was one of those misguided souls, until I finally saw the light.) Other people call *all* eigenclasses metaclasses. (Unfortunately, one of those people is the author of one the most popular tutorials on Ruby metaprogramming and the Ruby object model.) Some popular libraries add a `metaclass` method to `Object` that returns the object's eigenclass (e.g. ActiveSupport, Facets, metaid). Some people call *all* virtual classes (i.e. eigenclasses and include classes) metaclasses. Some people call `Class` the metaclass. Even within the Ruby source code itself, the word "metaclass" is used to refer to things that are not metaclasses.

Comment: Thanks for the post. That's is basically exactly what I was looking for. Now hopefully someone with more Python knowledge can comment or post about the various Python features.

Comment: The question has changed since I originally answered, but I decided to create a new answer instead of editing this one, and leave this one up, mainly in the hope that it will be of use to someone ending up here after a search for "ruby python metaclass" or something like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The intent of the question was to learn about metaclasses in both languages. I added the first edit when I realized my understanding of them in Python was wrong. Sorry if that confused you. Both of your answers have been very helpful in learning about Ruby's features.

Answer (score 13):

Your updated question looks quite different now. If I understand you correctly, you want to hook into object allocation and initialization, which has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with metaclasses. (But you *still* don't write what it is that you actually want to do, so I might still be off.)

In some object-oriented languages, objects are created by constructors. However, Ruby doesn't have constructors. Constructors are just factory methods (with stupid restrictions); there is no reason to have them in a well-designed language, if you can just use a (more powerful) factory method instead.

Object construction in Ruby works like this: object construction is split into two phases, *allocation* and *initialization*. Allocation is done by a public class method called `allocate`, which is defined as an instance method of class `Class` and is generally *never* overriden. (In fact, I don't think you actually *can* override it.) It just allocates the memory space for the object and sets up a few pointers, however, the object is not really usable at this point.

That's where the initializer comes in: it is an instance method called `initialize`, which sets up the object's internal state and brings it into a consistent, fully defined state which can be used by other objects.

So, in order to fully create a new object, what you need to do is this:

```
x = X.allocate
x.initialize
```

[Note: Objective-C programmers may recognize this.]

However, because it is too easy to forget to call `initialize` and as a general rule an object should be fully valid after construction, there is a convenience factory method called `Class#new`, which does all that work for you and looks something like this:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate
    obj.initialize(*args, &block)

    return obj
  end
end
```

[Note: actually, `initialize` is private, so reflection has to be used to circumvent the access restrictions like this: `obj.send(:initialize, *args, &block)`]

That, by the way, is the reason why to construct an object you *call* a public class method `Foo.new` but you *implement* a private instance method `Foo#initialize`, which seems to trip up a lot of newcomers.

However, *none* of this is in any way baked into the language. The fact that the primary factory method for any class is usually called `new` is just a convention (and sometimes I wish it were different, because it looks similar to constructors in Java, but is *completely* different). In other languages, the constructor must have a specific name. In Java, it must have the same name as the class, which means that a) there can be only one constructor and b) anonymous classes can't have constructors because they don't have names. In Python, the factory method must be called `__new__`, which again means there can be only one. (In both Java and Python, you can of course have different factory methods, but calling them looks different from calling the default, while in Ruby (and Smalltalk from whence this pattern originated) it looks just the same.)

In Ruby, there can be as many factory methods as you like, with any name you like, and a factory method can have many different names. (For collection classes, for example, the factory method is often aliased to `[]`, which allows you to write `List[1, 2, 3]` instead of `List.new(1, 2, 3)` which ends looking more like an array, thus emphasizing the collection-ish nature of lists.)

In short:

- the standardized factory method is `Foo.new`, but it can be anything
- `Foo.new` calls `allocate` to allocate memory for an empty object `foo`
- `Foo.new` then calls `foo.initialize`, i.e. the `Foo#initialize` instance method
- all three of those are just methods like any other, which you can undefine, redefine, override, wrap, alias and whatnot
- well, except `allocate` which needs to allocate memory inside the Ruby runtime which you can't really do from Ruby

In Python, `__new__` roughly corresponds to both `new` and `allocate` in Ruby, and `__init__` *exactly* corresponds to `initialize` in Ruby. The main difference is that in Ruby, `new` calls `initialize` whereas in Python, the *runtime* automatically calls `__init__` after `__new__`.

For example, here is a class which only allows a maximum of 2 instances created:

```
class Foo
  def self.new(*args, &block)
    @instances ||= 0
    raise 'Too many instances!' if @instances >= 2

    obj = allocate
    obj.send(:initialize, *args, &block)

    @instances += 1

    return obj
  end

  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

one = Foo.new('#1')
two = Foo.new('#2')
puts two.name         # => #2
three = Foo.new('#3') # => RuntimeError: Too many instances!
```

Comment: don't you need `obj = super` ? :)

Comment: @banister: Yeah, you're right. I switched it around at the last minute to make sure that I don't increment `@instances` before the object is actually successfully constructed and forgot to test it. I just switched it back, since that is probably overkill for such a small bit of sample code. In a real system, you'd probably put it in an `else` exception block.

Comment: @banister: Actually, the whole thing was badly thought out.